# Why won't my multifuntion printer scan directly after being unused for a few hours?

Tags: scanner, timeout, dell-optiplex

After a prolonged period — overnight — I lose the ability to initiate a scan directly from my multifunction printer. I'll initiate a job, and after a while, it will time out and beep. However, when I go to the PC and initiate a scan from there, the scan job goes through just fine. I can then initiate scans directly from the unit until another prolonged period (overnight). Then I have to do the process again. I've made sure all powersave settings are off. The PC doesn't go to sleep or into a powersave state. Any insight into this will be appreciated.

Pertinent Info:

- Unit: Dell 2155cdn Multifunction
- Connected via USB
- PC: Dell Optiplex 755

Comment: Is the PC in hibernate or sleep mode when you try and initiate the first (failing) scan

Comment: No.  Sleep mode and all other power related features are on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not appear to be the only one with this problem, as per recent posts on [**Dell's website**](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/peripherals/f/3528/p/19358146/19826987.aspx).

One workaround mentioned on the forum is to connect via a network cable instead of via USB.  If you do not have a hub/switch nearby, investing in a cheap [ethernet cross-over cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) will do the trick.

Comment: thanks..i read the same from the dell site.. you may have even read the post i commented on.  thanks for checking though!